# GNU Guile SCM to char*

Tags: memory, scheme, gnu, guile

I am relative new to FFI and GNU Guile, and I am writing bindings to a library that heavily uses `char*` variables. Here is code from function, that wraps C function:

```
static inline char*
scm_to_ascii_string(SCM string)
{
  return SCM_UNBNDP(SCM) ?  NULL
    : scm_to_stringn(string, NULL, "ascii", SCM_FAILED_CONVERSION_ERROR);
}

SCM_DEFINE(func, "func", ...)
{
  ...
  char *server_pass = scm_to_ascii_string(scm_server_pass);
  char *username = scm_to_ascii_string(scm_username);
  char *realname = scm_to_ascii_string(scm_realname);
}
```

Problem is that any call to conversion function can throw error, leaving me with memory leak.
What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

You could make the output part an argument eg:

void scm_to_ascii_string(SCM string, char* &out);

edit:

I guess you meant what exception handler methods are there on the c side, I think there might be something on that in the manual in one of the two sections on programming stuff in C.